# Preventing NHibernate foreign key creation for <any> mapping

Tags: nhibernate, foreign-keys, any

Is there a way from preventing SchemaExport from generating a foreign key constraint on
 mapping type? I saw a similar question about  mapping, but unfortunately that wont do for . I couldn't find answer to this in NHibernate reference, but maybe someone knows a trick? I'd like to avoid removing constraint afterwards.

Comment: Still couldn't figure out why ForeginKey is created as it shouldnt. Excerpt from documentation "It is impossible to specify a foreign key constraint for this kind of association, so this is most certainly not meant as the usual way of mapping (polymorphic) associations"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post your mappings? `<any>` definitely does *not* create foreign keys.

Example:

```
<any id-type="Guid" meta-type="Int32" name="FooBarOrBaz">
  <meta-value value="1" class="Foo" />
  <meta-value value="2" class="Bar" />
  <meta-value value="3" class="Baz" />
  <column name="FooBarOrBazId" />
  <column name="FooBarOrBazType" />
</any>
```

This will just create two columns (FooBarOrBazId and FooBarOrBazType), with no FKs

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry I wasted your time. It was created by reverse mappings. Now I have to go back to few other places where I asked the question and apologize too :)